Empty passport pages for Schengen visa
Do the Schengen embassies and USA embassy require opposing pages facing each other empty, or front back side empty of one page, for visa sticker?

For Schengen visa, this question already has answers here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21317/schengen-visa-in-almost-full-passport?rq=1

This question is similar to: Blank passport pages required for B2 visa to the United States. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
